# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, email, ssl, outlook

```
this is my code: 
<?php
functionrequire 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'papteste@outlook.pt';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'Teresapaula1';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port =   587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('papteste@outlook.pt', 'Fernando Alves');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Im using php mailer to send and email throught my form but that error keep pushing my nerves.im one day to finish this project and i can't solve this!!It also said that the error is in line 2 "functionrequire 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';". If you all could help me i would be mutch mutch thankfull!! :)

Comment: What the heck is `functionrequire`?

Comment: remove function from functionrequire 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

Comment: but if i remove function it giveme this "Warning: require(zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\www\zMovie\contact.php on line 2

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\php5') in C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\www\zMovie\contact.php on line 2"

Comment: @FernandoAlves - then it's telling you that you're looking in the wrong place for that file.

Comment: @andrewsi  but the problem its that the file its located in www/zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload and i dont know what to do.

Comment: @FernandoAlves - it looks like `contact.php` is also in the `zMovie/` directory, so you might just need `require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'`

Comment: @andrewsi  
but if i put only that it give me this error Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl

Comment: @FernandoAlves - that is a new question, then - presumably you need to install openssl

Comment: @andrewsi man i downloaded the folder of openssl and nothing i put right in my phpmailer folder and nothing yet.

Comment: @FernandoAlves - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting - you need to install openssl as part of the PHP installation; just downloading the folder into PHPMailer's folder won't do it

Answer (score 0):

The line should probably read

```
require 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Comment: but if i remove function it giveme this "Warning: require(zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\www\zMovie\contact.php on line 2 Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'zMovie/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\php5') in C:\Users\Nazista\Desktop\soft\www\zMovie\contact.php on line 2"

Comment: point it to the location of your PHPMailerAutoload.php file - i guess it will be `require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`

Comment: but if i put only that it give me this error Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl

Comment: Well then you are missing the openssl extension. Read the errors, man. And use google then.

Comment: man i downloaded the folder of openssl and nothing i put right in my phpmailer folder and nothing yet.